# Why ref.read(myProvider.notifier).getData() need to use initState become a late Future variable then could been use in future?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-futurebuilder

I am the new guy who learn flutter about 4 months, and I can't understand this:

There is two code:

Code 1.

```
late Future _placesFuture;

@override
void initState() {
  _placesFuture = ref.read(placesProvider.notifier).getData();
  super.initState();
}

FutureBuilder(
  future: _placesFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
      ? const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
      : places.isEmpty
          ? const Center(
              child: Text('No item here.'),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => PlaceItem(places[index]),
              itemCount: places.length,
            ),
)
```

Code 2.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: ref.read(placesProvider.notifier).getData(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
      ? const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
      : places.isEmpty
          ? const Center(
              child: Text('No item here.'),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => PlaceItem(places[index]),
              itemCount: places.length,
            ),
)
```

They only Code 1 can work, Code 2 will always been `ConnectionState.waiting`.

I don't know why I must `initState` _placesFuture first and then use `_placesFuture` in future.

Why could not just put `ref.read(placesProvider.notifier).getData()` in the future?

Thanks

I'm try to Google and ask to ChatGPT, but I still feel confused.

The whole code:

```
// places_provider.dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;

import '../models/place.dart';

Future<sql.Database> _getDb() async {
  final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
  final db = await sql.openDatabase(
    path.join(dbPath, 'places.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute('CREATE TABLE places(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, image TEXT, lat REAL, lng REAL, address TEXT)');
    },
    version: 1,
  );
  return db;
}

class PlacesNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Place>> {
  PlacesNotifier() : super([]);

  Future<void> removePlace(Place place) async {
    final db = await _getDb();
    db.delete('places', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [place.id]);
    if (state.contains(place)) {
      state = state.where((element) => element.id != place.id).toList();
    }
  }

  Future<void> addPlace(Place place) async {
    final db = await _getDb();

    db.insert('places', {
      'id': place.id,
      'title': place.title,
      'image': place.image.path,
      'lat': place.location.lat,
      'lng': place.location.lng,
      'address': place.location.address,
    });

    state = [place, ...state];
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final db = await _getDb();
    final data = await db.query('places');
    final p = data
        .map(
          (e) => Place(
            id: e['id'] as String,
            title: e['title'] as String,
            image: File(e['image'] as String),
            location: PlaceLocation(
              lat: e['lat'] as double,
              lng: e['lng'] as double,
              address: e['address'] as String,
            ),
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    state = p;
  }
}

final placesProvider = StateNotifierProvider<PlacesNotifier, List<Place>>(
  (ref) {
    return PlacesNotifier();
  },
);

// places_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import '../providers/places_provider.dart';
import '../models/place.dart';
import '../widgets/place_item.dart';
import './new_place_screen.dart';

class PlacesScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const PlacesScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<PlacesScreen> createState() => _PlacesScreenState();
}

class _PlacesScreenState extends ConsumerState<PlacesScreen> {
  late Future _placesFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _placesFuture = ref.read(placesProvider.notifier).getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final places = ref.watch(placesProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('我的所有秘密基地'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final p = await Navigator.of(context).push<Place>(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const NewPlaceScreen(),
                ));
                ref.read(placesProvider.notifier).addPlace(p!);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add))
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _placesFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : places.isEmpty
                ? const Center(
                    child: Text('尚未添加任何地點。'),
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => PlaceItem(places[index]),
                    itemCount: places.length,
                  ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or view in [GitHub](https://github.com/WangShuan/flutter-06-favorite-places/blob/main/lib/screens/places_screen.dart).

Comment: please share `getData()` body.

Comment: also Where does the  `ref` var come from?

Comment: see my video https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg for why creating a future in the future: param of the FutureBuilder is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should always use the style like Code 1.
Because if you put the request in `FutureBuilder`, it will make another call to the database Whenever the Widget rebuild.

In your Code 2, because `ref.watch(placesProvider);` is called with the ref of `PlacesScreen`, `PlacesScreen` will rebuild whenever `placesProvider` updates, and calling `ref.read(placesProvider.notifier).getData()`  in `FutureBuilder` will cause a delayed update `placesProvider` and trigger a rebuild of `PlacesScreen` which also rebuild `FutureBuilder` and call `ref.read(placesProvider.notifier).getData();` again.